# Installation error of Tesseract-OCR module for Python3x

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ocr, python-tesseract

I want to use tesseract-ocr lib with python-3.4. I download tesseract with "sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr" and now i can use it at command line.
But i want to use it with python3. But i couldn't find any tutorial for use native tesseract with python3x.

Actually i tried to use a wrapper like pytesseract. I download from https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/wiki/Python3Tesseract and install it with dpkg. I tried to import it but i get a strange error.

The error message is;
"ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/_tesseract.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _Z11GetUTF8TextPN9tesseract11TessBaseAPIE"

I tried tesserPy wrapper for python3x. It is working good for turkish, english but not working for arabic. (I tested tesserpy for just those languages.) 
You can get tesserpy from that address;
https://github.com/blindsightcorp/tesserpy

and here is my error message while i run tesserpy for arabic language;

tessdata_manager.SeekToStart(TESSDATA_INTTEMP):Error:Assert failed:in file adaptmatch.cpp, line 511

Has anybody see this kind of error message before ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I edit my question today and i told i could make ocr with tesserpy for english and turkish language. Most probably tesserpy works for all language. 
But i had still had a problem. I couldn't run tesserpy for arabic scripts. So i continued to search and found pyocr. It is working for arabic scripts also. You can clone and use it easily from git;

[PyOcr github repository](https://github.com/jflesch/pyocr)

I hope this issue may guide someone.